# Why do I get this Redux Toolkit error (Tag type was used, but not specified in `tagTypes`!)?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a React Native application, and I am currently working on configuring it to fetch and mutate data from a DB using my API. Specifically, I am using `createApi()` from react redux toolkit to achieve that.

At this point I only have

- a mutation to obtain a token
- a query to get the user information, which uses said token

I am currently trying to invalidate the cached user information when another token mutation happens (as it may be a new user logging in). Eventually there will, of course, be a logout in the middle, but for now this is my objective.

This is the code of my Api service:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';

export const myApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'myApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'http://myApiServerUrl/api/',
        tagTypes: ['User'],
        prepareHeaders: async (headers) => {
            headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
            const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('access_token');
            if (token) {
                headers.set('authorization', token);
            }
            return headers;
        }
    }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getToken: builder.mutation({
            query: (body) => ({
                url: 'token',
                method: 'POST',
                body,
            }),
            invalidatesTags: [{type: 'User', id: 'me'}]
        }),
        getMe: builder.query({
            query: () => `user/me`,
            providesTags: (result) => (result ? [{type: 'User', id: 'me'}] : [])
        }),
    })
})

export const { useGetTokenMutation, useGetMeQuery } = myApi;
```

This actually **works**! But I get the following error:

```
 ERROR  Tag type 'User' was used, but not specified in `tagTypes`!
```

Do you all know what am I doing wrong? It really seems like the tags are defined in the exact correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was simply defining it wrong. The `tagTypes` parameter is to be defined on the `createApi` input object, instead of where I was placing it.

Therefore, the first lines of code

```
export const myApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'myApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'http://myApiServerUrl/api/',
        tagTypes: ['User'],
```

should instead be

```
export const myApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'myApi',
    tagTypes: ['User'],
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'http://myApiServerUrl/api/',
```

and this does work.